# What is a Pro-Chancellor?

Tags: titles, administration, job

I was looking at a document describing setting arrangements for a ceremony and ran into the phrase:

> The president of the Student Guild shall sit in the front row, with
>   the Vice-chancellor, the Chancellor, and the **Pro-Chancellor**

What is a Pro-chancellor?
I've never heard of one before.

In-case this is a regional term, I am at a Australian university.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "pro-chancellor" (or similarly a "pro-rector," which we have in Germany), is a deputy to a chancellor (or rector), who handles certain duties on behalf of the chancellor (or rector). In the particular case of Commonwealth countries from which you hail, the pro-chancellor is the person who heads the university's executive council on behalf of the chancellor.

Comment: This is correct. It's a usage that dates back to Roman times! "Pro" in Latin means "for" in the sense of "on behalf of". The pro-consul is a person whom the consul has authorized to act with his authority on his behalf, for instance.